# Lofting a shape over two paths

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, shape-keys

I have been having a heck of a time with trying to create a unique shape that requires lofting a shape over two curves /rail. This is possible to do in Fusion 360 with relative ease, but I know no such equivalent for blender.

for the sake of this example, we have the model image here:
[image]

target shape "green hammer/rear assembly bit" (i will Duplicate and extrude for the white part before boolianing):
[image: https://puu.sh/Gnfei/b5fdd21d6d.png]

and the base shapes/keys here:
[image]

as you can see by my blender image, im trying to extrude the back wall against the x and Z-axis (or any other combination) to achieve the loft transition from a vaguely half hexagonal shape to an egged dome shape. I've tried everything I know over the last two weeks and just do not have a good solution yet, nor am I sure there IS a good solution. I could def use some guidance

Comment: you might be better off box modelling it, from a cube with subsurf like this: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/QSjMMqRd/

Comment: Wow that is super cool! i had no idea edges could be bent that way. I know about beveling and Catmull clark subsurface, but i dont know how to do what youve shown me here!

. I will google the methods you are showing me, thank you. It may help. im a stickler for accuracy, and this may help me achieve that.

Comment: you're welcome. To be fair the bendy edges thing is just visualisation, if you disable it you'll see that the base shape is very simple, the most important is marking the creases (shift+E) and setting the flat/smooth shadings right